# R - Fill Column with values from any other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data frame of 5 columns: 4 columns have values and the 1 column that is empty. I want to fill the empty column with any value from any of the 4 columns.

Let's assume this is my dataframe `df`:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
  11   11    
   2         2    2
       23
   4         4
       15        15
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
  11   11             11
   2         2    2    2
       23             23
   4         4         4
       15        15   15
```

**EDIT** I applied the answers provided by everyone, but it still isn't working for some reason. If it helps, this is the `dput(head(df))` of my actual data:

```
structure(list(Treat_One = c("      ", "5 2012", "4 2008", "4 2010", 
"      ", "2 2008"), Treat_Two = c("8 2010", "5 2012", "4 2008", 
"4 2010", "8 2011", "2 2008"), Treat_Three = c("      ", "5 2012", 
"4 2008", "4 2010", "8 2011", "2 2008"), Treat_Four = c("      ", 
"      ", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      ")), .Names = c("Treat_One", 
"Treat_Two", "Treat_Three", "Treat_Four"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Edit** Included `str(df)`

```
'data.frame':   209 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Treat_One  : chr  "      " "5 2012" "4 2008" "4 2010" ...
 $ Treat_Two  : chr  "8 2010" "5 2012" "4 2008" "4 2010" ...
 $ Treat_Three: chr  "      " "5 2012" "4 2008" "4 2010" ...
 $ Treat_Four : chr  "      " "      " "      " "      " ...
```

Comment: if row 3 would be blank (no value 3 for Col2) you would like to have a blank in Col5 or is it simply the solution provided below?

Comment: If I understand your question, none of the columns will be blank, so it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It seems like you always have the same value per row. You could just do `df$Col5 <- rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)` for instance.

Comment: You should provide `dput(head(df))` instead.

Comment: please show us the output of `str(your.data.frame)` to help us understand the empty cells better (are you really sure they contain NAs?)

Comment: @RYoda They originally had `NA` values, but I figured a way around the issue by simply replacing `NA` with blanks.

Comment: Not sure what's the point in replacing `NA`s with those awkward spaces, but you could do `df$five <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df != "      "))]`

Comment: Had the same issue: Not all of the values transferred over to the new column.

Comment: This maybe? `do.call(pmax, df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new data provided by the OP we can remove leading/trailing white spaces with `trimws`

```
df$Treat_Four <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(x[trimws(x) != ""], 1))
df

#    Treat_One Treat_Two Treat_Three Treat_Four
#1              8 2010                 8 2010
#2    5 2012    5 2012      5 2012     5 2012
#3    4 2008    4 2008      4 2008     4 2008
#4    4 2010    4 2010      4 2010     4 2010
#5              8 2011      8 2011     8 2011
#6    2 2008    2 2008      2 2008     2 2008
```

**Original Answer**

We can use `apply` row-wise and take 1 `sample` of the element which is not equal to empty string

```
df$Col5 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(x[x != ""], 1))
df
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
#1    1    1              1
#2    2         2    2    2
#3         3              3
#4    4         4         4
#5         5         5    5
```

---

If there are `NA` values and not blanks we can use the same logic

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(x[!is.na(x)], 1))
```

Comment: @user2105555 added an answer to handle `NA` values

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work with I have NA in Col1. I included the head() of my data in the original post.

Comment: @user2105555 Based on the new data provided, added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply type as following:
    `df$Col5 <- 1:5`
`df$Col5` will create a `Col5` in `df` and `1:5` just add the series number there.

Comment: I think this will not work cause it adds a hard coded number into col5 instead of using the value from the first non-empty column in the same row (as requested by the OP)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, NA, 3), col2 = c(1, 2, NA), col3 = c(NA, 2, 3),col4 = rep(NA, 3))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df[i, 4] <- df[i, which(!is.na(df[i,]))][, 1]
}
df
```

That will produce:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, NA, 3), col2 = c(1, 2, NA), col3 = c(NA, 2, 3), col4 = rep(NA, 3))
> df
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    1   NA   NA
2   NA    2    2   NA
3    3   NA    3   NA
> for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
+     df[i, 4] <- df[i, which(!is.na(df[i,]))][, 1]
+ }
+ df
+ 
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    1   NA    1
2   NA    2    2    2
3    3   NA    3    3
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work with I have `NA` in Col1. I included the `head()` of my data in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a vectorized option with `max.col`

```
df$Treat_Four <- df[1:3][cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(sapply(df[1:3], trimws)!='', "first"))]
df
#   Treat_One Treat_Two Treat_Three Treat_Four
#1              8 2010                 8 2010
#2    5 2012    5 2012      5 2012     5 2012
#3    4 2008    4 2008      4 2008     4 2008
#4    4 2010    4 2010      4 2010     4 2010
#5              8 2011      8 2011     8 2011
#6    2 2008    2 2008      2 2008     2 2008
```